# Pandas Query Fails

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following CSV:

```
ID,Title,Created By,Created On,Estimate,Forecast,Priority,References,Section,Section Depth,Section Description,Suite,Suite ID,Type,Updated By,Updated On
C28045,test1,dsa,10/27/2022 1:56 AM,,,Highest,,primary,0,,Master,S378,Automated,test,10/27/2022 4:33 AM
C28060,test32,dsa,10/27/2022 4:34 AM,,,Medium,,primary,0,,Master,S378,Automated,test,10/27/2022 4:34 AM
C28062,test5,dsa,10/27/2022 4:34 AM,,,Medium,,primary,0,,Master,S378,Automated,test,10/27/2022 4:34 AM
C28059,test6,dsa,10/27/2022 4:06 AM,,,Medium,,sec,0,,Master,S378,Automated,test,10/27/2022 4:33 AM
C28061,test643,dsa,10/27/2022 4:34 AM,,,Medium,,sec,0,,Master,S378,Automated,test,10/27/2022 4:34 AM
C28063,tes4352,dsa,10/27/2022 4:34 AM,,,Medium,,sec,0,,Master,S378,Automated,test,10/27/2022 4:34 AM
```

Using pandas I want to return the ID, for a given "Section" and "Title"

```
data = pd.read_csv(csvPath)
data.query('Section = primary and Title = test32', inplace=True)
print(data)
```

Raises:

```
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    Section =primary and Title =test32 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Python keyword not valid identifier in numexpr query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a few quotes and should be using '=='

```py
# using query, filter for Section == 'primary' and Title == 'test32'
data.query("Section == 'primary' and Title == 'test32'", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Any idea how I would get only the value for ID column from the result?
`data.get("ID")` prints "0 12321qwe" basically a 0 space and the id value, I'd like to get just the value for the ID column as string

Comment: Answer is data["ID"].item()

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```py
data = pd.read_csv(csvPath)

data=data[(data['Section']=='primary' & data['Title']=='test32')]
```